# Windows 10 block assembly after restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I have installed my program to windows 10 to %ProgramFiles% path. After some time, after auto-restart Windows (after update?) my program doesn't run. In event viewer I have follow error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=2.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Now in program folder Common.Logging.dll is blocked. Who blocked this assembly and how to prevent this in future?

Comment: BadImageFormatException usually has to do with a program running as a 64-bit process and a DLL containing 32-bit code. Check your project for that type of error.

Comment: @Pikoh if I unblick assembly via file->properties program work correctly